# I can't ping by hostname - Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have an ubuntu server. From a computer on the network when I ping IP of ubuntu server is fine and responds. If it is ping by hostname - "Ping request could not find host ubuntu-vm.spkso.local. Please check the name and try again."

/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

> ```
> network:   version: 2   ethernets:
> ens160:
>   addresses: [192.168.3.3/24]
>   gateway4: 192.168.3.6
>   nameservers:
>     addresses: [192.168.3.9, 192.168.3.20]
> ```

/etc/hostname

> ubuntu-vm

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 192.168.9
nameserver 192.168.20
options edns0 trust-ad
```

Comment: Do you have a record for `ubuntu-vm.spkso.local` in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: @Matigo

192.168.3.3     ubuntu-vm               ubuntu-vm
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment you left, I would hazard a guess that your `/etc/hosts` file *on the host* is incomplete. You might want to have it set like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.3.3     ubuntu-vm.spkso.local ubuntu-vm

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

If you know the IPv6 address for your VM, do throw it in at the end of the file. Once this file is set, you should be able to `ping ubuntu-vm` and `ping ubuntu-vm-spkso.local` as the names will resolve to the correct local address.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same .. I have no ideas anymore.

Comment: I have same you problem. Did you found solution?